# How can i move the file or folder to another folder in google drive api?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I did everything as in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder). But that doesn't work for me. I have corrected this script a bit:

```
window.gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        fileId: fileId,
        fields: 'parents'
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        window.gapi.client.drive.files.update({
          fileId: this.fileData.id,
          addParents: folderId,
          removeParents: res.result.parents[0],
          fields: 'id, parents'
        }).then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
      })
```

It now moves the file to a different location, but does not delete the current location. That is, after working out my code, it is like copying a file, and not moving it.

Comment: Can you confirm you have removed all the parents from the file and added the correct ones? @Mikhail

Comment: Correction it copies the file to the new location you need to delete the old one.

Comment: I'm not sure that I am deleting all parents and that I am deleting at least one. How do I remove them correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you are using removes only the first parent.

In order to remove all the parents correctly you will have to add the following line to your code:

```
var previousParents = res.result.parents.join(',');
```

And when calling the `update` method, you will have to remove `previousParents`:

```
removeParents: previousParents,
```

#### Reference

- [Drive API Move Files Between Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#moving_files_between_folders).